# Stopping only one thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, thread-sleep

I have many threads in my application, how do I stop only one thread from them? If I use `Thread.Sleep()` it stops the whole application, I just want to stop a single thread. How do I do that? I am using c#.

Comment: Thread.Sleep should not halt your program if it's running on its own thread. Can you show some code?

Comment: I suggest you read this free ebook: [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: How are you creating the threads? ThreadPool? The Thread class? Do you know exactly which thread you want to stop or will any do?

Comment: Ok, thanku you for the book :) @NicholasButler and yes Jordan Kaye it was problem in my code, it is not halting the program now working fine. Thankyou any ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `Thread.Sleep()` you are stopping only thread, which called this method. If your main thread (i.e. UI thread) calls `Thread.Sleep()`, then application freezes (actually other threads continue working, but UI is not refreshed). So, if you want to stop some thread, then:

- it should not be main thread
- just call `Thread.Sleep()` on that thread

Example (assume this code is executed on main thread):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoSomething);
Thread.Sleep(1000); // this will freeze application
```

And this is a callback (which is executed on background thread):

```
static void DoSomething(object state)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // this will not freeze application
}
```