# Trying to finish only one thread from various

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

First of all, I must clarify that I'm very new working with threads. Now, I have an application that executes multiple threads but in different times. I mean, I have objects that each of them executes a thread in a certain moment.

I'm gonna be more specific. I have a list of task, each associated to a particular object. When I click of a button (that apply to that object), the task associated starts to run. In a certain moment, I can have more than one thread. That works correctly. The problem is when I finish one of them. I finish one thread, all of the rest stop too.

Of course, there is something wrong in my implementation. I don't understand why all threads are stopped.

Here is my implementation (I'm working in MVC on Windows Application Forms):

In the main forms I have

```
//This method starts when I press a button from a specific object
private void StartTask( int idtask )
    {

        int counter = this.Controller.GetTasksSize(); //This is a List<ObjectTask>, this method returns the count

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            //GetTasks() returns the List<ObjectTask>
            if (this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].idtask == idtask)
            {
                ThreadStart tsTask = new ThreadStart(() => TaskLoop(this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].idtask,
                                                                    this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].time,
                                                                    this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].Mode));
                Thread task = new Thread(tsTask);
                this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].task = task;
                this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].task.Start();
                task = null;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

private void StopTask(int idtask)
    {

        int counter = this.Controller.GetTasksSize();

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            if (this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].idtask == idtask)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].task != null && this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].task.IsAlive)
                       this.Controller.GetTasks()[i].task.Abort();

                }
                catch (ThreadAbortException e)
                {

                }

                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

My list of ObjectTask is

```
public class ObjectTask
{
    private int idtask;
    public int idtask
    {
        get { return idtask; }
        set { idtask = value; }
    }

    private int time;
    public int time
    {
        get { return time; }
        set { time = value; }
    }

    private bool Mode;
    public bool Mode
    {
        get { return Mode; }
        set { Mode = value; }
    }

    private Thread task;
    public Thread task
    {
        get { return task; }
        set { task = value; }
    }
}
```

At the same time, when I stop one thread, I can see the following message on the console:

The thread '' (0x1764) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I've been searching and also I saw these questions

- [A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973149/a-first-chance-exception-of-type-system-threading-threadabortexception-occurre)
- [System.Threading.ThreadAbortException occurred in mscorlib.dll occuring persitently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131717/system-threading-threadabortexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-dll-occuring-persiten)
- [Stopping only one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202902/stopping-only-one-thread)
- [Multi Threading C# Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614490/multi-threading-c-sharp-windows-forms)

but no one help me.

If it is necessary more information, please let me know.

Comment: Whenever you run any code in thread you must handle ThreadExeption for that method so it exits gracefully

Comment: Sorry, The name of the question was changed. I put C# Windows Form App. I will try to edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Thread class, why don't you use the Tasking Library? (ref
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx)

you can then use the WaitAll function to wait for all tasks to finish. (ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)